# Most pervasive GIS formats?

Tags: file-formats

Where can one find out what the most pervasive GIS formats are?

For example, from the [GIS file formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIS_file_formats) Wikipedia page, there 4 broad categories, each with many popular formats.

1. **Raster formats** (13 formats listed)
2. **Vector formats** (19)
3. **Grid formats** (4)
4. **Other formats** (5)

This is a dizzying array of alternatives, each with their own reasons for existence.

**In terms of general formats though, what are the most pervasive ones in use?**

*Edit: By pervasive, I'm looking for say the top 3 formats that would be encountered if a company that used GIS data was randomly selected out of all companies using GIS data*

Comment: One wonders what "most pervasive" might mean.  Arguably, a format is "pervasive" only if it shows up on that Wikipedia page, in which case the question answers itself.  Does the interest lie in amount of data stored in a format?  Number of entities using a format?  Recent rates of increase in the rate of use of a format?  Size and visibility of the organizations adopting a format?  Number of software programs natively using (or importing? exporting?) a format?  Total user base of said programs?  Etc., etc.

Comment: Agreed, what kind of answer are you expecting, lists of formats used/supported by particular communities, industries or software packages? Seems too broad to be answerable without some guidelines.

Comment: I agree that the definition of pervasive is important. But I don't think I would ever argue that a format is pervasive just because it shows up on wikipedia!

Comment: @Mark I agree, but you seem to have confused a conditional with its converse: *if* a format is "pervasive" (in certain senses related to being known to a wide spectrum of people) it's almost sure to show up on Wikipedia, but if it shows up on Wikipedia, well...who knows ;-).

Comment: Based on some of the answers you're getting, Dan, you might want to specify explicitly what you mean by "GIS format," too, rather than leaving it up to the Wikipedia link.  Otherwise this thread is going to list [every file format ever invented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats) :-).

Comment: I think the subject (format) is too subjective. If you have a software, the native format is the most pervasive format you know. Who knows ALL the software EVERYONE has, and what format they utilize in it, and why does that matter?  A general perspective as Mark noted "we see a lot of data and the most common formats we see" is about the best answer anyone could give.

Comment: If the question had some reasoning behind the need for the pervasiveness we might get to a consensus

Comment: @whuber - That's fair enough. If something is popular it is likely to appear on wikipedia. But the reverse is almost certainly not true.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, where to start.

Although you can divide data by vector/raster etc there are some obvious problems.
For example an Oracle database can store vector or raster (as can other databases).

I work at [Safe Software](http://www.safe.com) where we generally prefer to look at Spatial data (rather than just GIS) and so divide into different categories according to use.

- CAD
- GIS
- Raster
- Database
- BIM/3D
- Web
- Point Cloud

Whether this is a better categorization I'm not sure, but it does (I think) help determine whether a format is pervasive for a particular field.

Also, there is "pervasive" and then there is "best". Shape format is very pervasive in GIS, but I don't know that everyone will say it is the best. XML-based formats are up-and-coming since they work well for web delivery.

Anyway, we collect stats on most-used formats and I think I can probably share them since it's nothing you couldn't guess:

- GIS: Shape
- CAD: DWG
- Raster: GeoTIFF
- Database: Oracle and Geodatabase
- BIM: CityGML
- Web: WFS
- Point Cloud: LAS

But take a look at our web site for the [full list of formats we support](http://www.safe.com/fme/format-search/). There is a truly mind-boggling 300 spatial (or related) formats.

Comment: I remember seeing a slide showing a matrix of which input and output formats were the most popular in FME, do you have a link to that available? Of course Shapefile was #1 for both.

Comment: If you look at this slideshow (slide 25) there is a table of type translations (eg GIS->GIS, CAD->GIS, GIS->BIM etc). I'll see if I can find the format version: http://www.slideshare.net/SafeSoftware/taste-test-fme-2011-beyond-5519213

Comment: Note: There is a difference in 32-bit and 64-bit version of FME 2011/2012beta but it is down to the native vendor of that format not supporting 64-bit (not Safe's issue)

Comment: @Mark, I think that may have been the one I was thinking of actually. Thanks

Comment: @blah238 - there is a format version, but the only one I can find is from 2006. The opening session slides from our 2006 user conference, if you cared to look it up: http://www.fmeuc.com/archive/2006fmeuc.php

Comment: `Web: WFS` WFS is not a format though.  So GML is probably the correct format to be cited here.

Answer (score 12):

**Vector**

[Shapefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) (ESRI) [Tech Spec PDF](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=shapefile%20&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDkQFjAB&url=http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf&ei=bD-wTsqtLenu0gGvi4WvAQ&usg=AFQjCNHp9v_VCrbagYu23yPhKgqEO9KX8Q&sig2=0EpPGS-N3NuQ5xANTH0tIQ&cad=rja) 2.5 billion files est

[MapInfo Tab/MIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapInfo_TAB_format) (Pitney Bowes Business Insight) [Tech Spec](http://mitab.maptools.org/) 1.5 billion files est

[AutoCAD DWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dwg) (AutoDesk)** has 18 major variants of the DWG
"Autodesk estimates that in 1998 there were in excess of two billion DWG files in existence"

Fastest adopted format  is [KML/KMZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) Google Earth/Pro est 0.5 Billion files.

**Raster**

[Tiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format) Tagged Image File Format (GeoTiff)

[Jpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpeg) (Joint Photographic Experts Group)

[PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) (Portable Network Graphics)

Answer (score 3):

Any ESRI format, ESRI is the most used gis with 30% market share.  http://geothought.blogspot.com/2009/08/traditional-gis-vendor-market-share-for.html

Answer (score 1):

When talking about GIS *data exchange* formats, do not forget [GML](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/gml) as well.

Answer (score -1):

1. Shapefile
2. XLS (usually with loads of formatting and completely non-normalized)
3. XLSX (which you have to download a converter to open in Excel 2003)